# i2c bus speed issues

Tags: i2c, bus, speed

i'm using a MSP430F6736A the eUSCI_B0 i2c peripheral on my chip in INTERRUPT mode to communicate with a FRAM chip.

I'm trying to figure out why i have to drop my i2c clock to 130KHz in order to communicate "reliably" with a Rohm FEDR44V100A fram 1Mb chip.

To clarify, when i set the i2c clock to 400KHz, the FRAM chip 'sometimes' seems to send back just 0s (best case, or random data worst case), yet when i set the i2c clock to 130KHz, everything works superbly.
I am assuming it is the FRAM chip that is sending bad data & not the i2c port receiving bad data as i cannot "consistently" reproduce the error so as to capture it on a logic analyser.

From the FRAM datasheet, the chip can operate at clock speeds up to 1MHz.
My MSP430 is operating at 16.77MHz

the rise time on SCL & SDA is less than 200nS.
the pullup resistors on the i2c bus are 2K

the setup for the i2c is:

```
UCB0CTLW0 |= UCMST | UCMODE_3 |  UCSSEL__SMCLK;
UCB0BRW_L = 128; .................this is for 130KHz
UCB0BRW_L = 40;....................this is for 400KHz
UCB0BRW_H = 0;
UCB0I2COA0 = 0; 
UCB0I2CSA = theSalveAddress;
```

the interrupt bits of UCB0IE are set/cleared at the relevant times.

I might point out that i had no problems whatsover communicating to a Microchip 47L16 EERAM chip at 400KHz which would indicate the problem lies (100%) with the ROHM chip...but why?
Any pointers as to what i could do to try & improve the speed would be appreciated, as would any suggestions as to why the communication has to be at this low speed.

thanks in advance.

the circuit...
[image: the circuit]

clock wave at 129KHz..
[image: clock wave at 129KHz]

clock wave at 382KHz..
[image: clock wave at 382KHz]

Comment: could be pull-ups or supply decoupling capacitors

Comment: I2C is pretty reliable, especially at 400 kHz. Can you post a complete schematic of your (portion of) board, together with pictures of your setup? Is it on a PCB or on a breadboard? Do you have access to an oscilloscope? If yes, please post two snapshot where we can see a full transaction between the MSP and the FED, one at 130 kHz and one at 400 kHz.

Comment: circuit added..scope pics shortly
and yes..its on a pcb.

Comment: Ah, there is a upper limit of 400pf on the total capacitance of an I2C bus. If you decrease I2C speed to 100kHz or even lower, reduce wiring length, preferrably less than 30cm, twist wires etc, you can do I2C better. Another thing is the pullups. For Rpi for example, the built in pullup is 1k8, and if on the same bus, you add in more and more  I2C modules each with 4k7 pullups, then the equivalent pullups will be too strong for Rpi to pull down. I usually remove ALL on board smd pullups for a more reliable performance, getting I2C I/O Error #121.

Comment: waves added..

And, i'm not using the builtin pullups of the MCU.

Comment: Good job OP, we're getting there. In the snapshots you should include also SDA, and please also add a zoomed out version so that it is possible to see where the fail is occurring.

Comment: SDA wave is as good as the SCL which is why i didnt include it. I cannot add a zoomed out version as i never know when its going to happen...totally random which is a major part of the problem.

Comment: Understood, so you say there is no crosstalk at all. I also understand that you never see a nack, arbitration lost or anything like that - perhaps there is an error register somewhere, and some flag is getting set there, and as a consequence of some kind of error you get garbage data. Just an idea to where to look next.

Comment: it seems to me that at the higher speed the FRAM chip is misreading the address to read data from...OR...it misses the new read address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

When I used the Microchip EERAM chip, I found that I had to place a dummy byte in TxBUF immediately *before* setting the Tx interrupt i.e. like this:

```
UCB0TXBUF = 0x55; 
UCB0IE = UCTXIE0;
```

If I didn’t do this, the 1st byte of the address in the chip I wanted to write to, was not sent.

*However*, that line caused the problem with the FRAM chip as, *sometimes*, the 0x55 was actually transmitted as the 1st byte to set the address in the chip I wanted to write to.

I am unclear why this only happened *sometimes*. It was found by using a logic analyser to repeatedly grab 2 seconds worth of communications & I noticed the 0x55 when it should have been a different value transmitted (as well as the fact that 3 bytes were transmitted for the address & not just 2).

Further, in the ISR I also had the line `UCB0TXBUF = 0xFF;` immediately before I cleared the Tx interrupt i.e. like this:

```
UCB0TXBUF = 0xff; // to prevent UCB0IFG from having TXBuf empty flag
UCB0IE &= ~UCTXIE0; // disable TX intr
```

I have now changed this & now clear the IFG setting *after* disabling the interrupt i.e. like this:

```
UCB0IE &= ~UCTXIE0; 
UCB0IFG &= ~UCTXIFG0;
```

So thank you to all who tried to help, it is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I am now successfully communicating at 1 MHz.